# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

```
from scipy.io import wavfile

train_audio_path = 'E:/'
filename = 'file_example_WAV_1MG'
sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read(train_audio_path + filename)
print('sample rate : {}, samples.shape : {}'.format(sample_rate, samples.shape))

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-cd74bbc41446> in <module>
      3 train_audio_path = 'E:/'
      4 filename = 'file_example_WAV_1MG'
----> 5 sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read(train_audio_path + filename)
      6 print('sample rate : {}, samples.shape : {}'.format(sample_rate, samples.shape))

E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py in read(filename, mmap)
    262         mmap = False
    263     else:
--> 264         fid = open(filename, 'rb')
    265 
    266     try:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:/file_example_WAV_1MG'
```

I have a problem with my code. I tried to do everything but failed. I have no idea why this error is made. I changed path to everywhere from c to e but still not working at all. what's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
train_audio_path = 'E:\' OR 'E:\\'
```

change the direction of '\'

And don't forget to add the extension of your image file as well (i.e., jpg,png or any other). I also get this error multiple times in windows.Hope it helps.

Comment: SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
now this error is made. damn...  File "<ipython-input-1-779f48f38310>", line 3
    train_audio_path = 'E:\'
                            ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: try 'E:\\' this instead of single'\' and let me know if it works.

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:\\file_example_WAV_1MG' well same error i guess

Comment: what is the extension of your image file png or jpg or other?

Comment: wow the problem was the extension thx but                                      
 E:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:7: WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
  import sys                                                                                                                                                      this sentence in red box in coming. can you tell me what does it mean?

Comment: This is just a warning. You can ignore this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the extension. Perhaps `file_example_WAV_1MG.wav` ?
Check it on your computer.

Comment: can you explain more specifically? I have that file in my e drive.

Comment: Your filename does not have any extension, which is not natural in windows. Just check it if the other answer is not sufficient.